# OpenMPI communication issue

Tags: c++, pthreads, mpi

I am trying to work around this issue since few days now. I have a hybrid OpenMPI + Pthreads program. This means, the program runs on multiple machines such that each machine runs a set of pthreads.

To simplify the problem, let us assume there are 3 machines and each is running 2 pthreads: P1 and P2. Now, P1 on each machine continuously communicates with P1 on other machines using MPI_Send/Recv. Simultaneously, P2 does some work and regularly calls MPI_Barrier (to synchronize with P2 on other machines). This fails the MPI_Send/Recv methods and the program crashes with random errors like: connection reset by peer / bad file descriptor / tcp errors / etc.

1. If I comment out MPI_Barrier from P2, everything works fine.
2. If I comment out MPI_Send/Recv from P1, everything works fine.
3. If both MPI_Barrier in P2 and MPI_Send/Recv in P1 are left uncommented, the program crashes.

Hence, the only reason I could think of is that MPI_Barrier and MPI_Send/Recv are affecting each other at underlying communication levels.

However, I do need communication (like MPI_Send/Recv) in P1 and synchronization (like MPI_Barrier) in P2 to maintain semantic correctness. And I need them simultaneously (which means I do not want to pause communication before hitting the synchronization point and then continue the communication fro where it had left).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you use separate MPI communicators for sets of P1 and P2? Do P1 and P2 at the same machine synchronize between themselves in some way? It would be better if you provided your communication code (simplified down to communication/synchronization operations only).

Comment: Also, make yourself sure to initialize MPI with `MPI_Init_thread` with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` (and in no way with `MPI_Init`).

Comment: [1] I use the same default (MPI_COMM_WORLD) communicators for sets of P1 and P2.

[2] Yes, P1 and P2 on same machine synchronize using pthread synchronization. Basically during initialization, P2 signals P1 to start communication and during shutdown, P2 signals P1 to stop the communication. In a way, you can think of P2 as the master controlling P1 start-up and shut-down.

[3] I had initially planned to provide the minimal communication code from my existing code. But since the code is distributed across different files/methods, it was a little difficult to do so.

Comment: I initialize MPI with MPI_Init. Later, on each machine I create pthreads using pthread_create(). I am not aware of MPI_Init_thread; I will look into it.

Comment: Well, that explains a lot. An MPI implementation is not operating in thread-safe mode, so concurrent calls from several threads lead to all kind of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you get look mostly like an incorrectly initialized MPI (as if you called `MPI_Init` instead of `MPI_Init_thread` in a multi-threaded application). See http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-20-html/node165.htm .

I would also suggest you to use a separate MPI communicator at least for `MPI_Barrier()` call if the problem persists.

Comment: Yes. It was due to incorrect initialization of MPI. I am now using MPI_Init_thread with "MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE". Things work fine. Thanks Inspired.